# SQL Server 2008 - False error for "Msg 8120"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, common-table-expression

I am writing a query in SQL Server 2008 (Express I believe?). I am currently getting this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   Column 'AIM.dbo.AggTicket.TotDirectHrs' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I am trying to do a historical analysis of our production WIP (Work In Process). 
I have created a standalone calendar table (actually located in a separate database called BAS on the same server to not interfere with the ERP that operates the AIM database). I've been overwhelmed for days with some of the examples for creating running total queries/views/tables, so for now I'll just plan on taking care of that part inside of Crystal Reports 2016. My thinking was that I wanted to return records for each order each day of my calendar table (to be narrowed down in the future to only days that match records in the AIM database). The values I think I will need are:

- Record Date (not unique)
- Order Number (unique for each day)
- Estimated hours for the job
- The total number of hours worked on the job current as of today's date (in case the estimated hours were drastically underbudgeted)
- The SUM of the direct labor hours charged to the job on said record date
- The COUNT of the number of employees in attendance on said record date.
- The SUM of the hours attended by employees on said record date.

The tables I use are as follows:

BAS Database:

- dbo.DateDimension - Used for complete calendar of dates from 1/1/1987 to 12/31/2036

AIM Database:

- dbo.AggAttend - Contains one or more records for each employee's attendance duration on a given date (i.e. One record for each punch-in / punch-out. Should be equal to indirect + direct labor)
- dbo.AggTicket - Contains one or more records for each employee's direct labor duration charged to a particular order number
- dbo.ModOrders - Contains one record for each order including the estimated hours, start date, and end date (I will worry about using the start and end dates later for figuring out how many available hours there were on each date)

Here is the code I'm using in my query:

```
;WITH OrderTots AS
(
    SELECT
        AggTicket.OrderNo,
        SUM(AggTicket.TotDirectHrs) AS TotActHrs
    FROM
        AIM.dbo.AggTicket
    GROUP BY
        AggTicket.OrderNo
)
SELECT
    d.Date,
    t.OrderNo,
    o.EstHrs,
    OrderTots.TotActHrs,
    SUM(t.TotDirectHrs) OVER (PARTITION BY t.TicketDate) AS DaysDirectHrs,
    COUNT(a.EmplCode) AS NumEmployees,
    SUM(a.TotHrs) AS DaysAttendHrs
FROM
    BAS.dbo.DateDimension d
INNER JOIN 
    AIM.dbo.AggAttend a ON d.Date = a.TicketDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AIM.dbo.AggTicket t ON d.Date = t.TicketDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AIM.dbo.ModOrders o ON t.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OrderTots ON t.OrderNo = OrderTots.OrderNo
GROUP BY
    d.Date, t.TicketDate, t.OrderNo, o.EstHrs,
    OrderTots.TotActHrs
ORDER BY
    d.Date
```

When I run that query in SQL Server Management Studio 2017, I get the above error.

These are my questions for the community:

1. Does this error message correctly describe an error in my code?
2. If so, why is that error an error? (To the best of my knowledge, everything is already contained in either an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause...smh)
3. What is a better way to write this query so that it will function?

Much appreciation to everyone in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'd recommend you edit to summarize your question near or at the top of the post.  Then lazy programmers who TL;DR might be more encourage to help.  And don't apologize; you probably know more than half the people here.

Comment: Thanks @allanberry, I really appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am writing a query in SQL Server 2008 (Express I believe?).

`SELECT @@VERSION` Will let you know what version you are on.

> Column 'AIM.dbo.AggTicket.TotDirectHrs' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

The problem is with your `SUM OVER()` statement:

```
SUM(t.TotDirectHrs) OVER (PARTITION BY t.TicketDate) AS DaysDirectHrs
```

Here, since you are using the `OVER` clause, you must include it in the `GROUP BY`. The `OVER` clause is used to determine the partitioning and order of a row-set for a **window function**. So, while you are using an aggregate with `SUM` you are doing this in a **window function**. Window functions belong to a type of function known as a 'set function', which means a function that applies to a set of rows. The word 'window' is used to refer to the set of rows that the function works on.

Thus, add `t.TotDirectHrs` to the `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY
    d.Date, t.TicketDate, t.OrderNo, o.EstHrs,
    OrderTots.TotActHrs, t.TotDirectHrs
```

If this narrows your results into a grouping that you don't want, then you can wrap it in another `CTE` or use a correlated sub-query. *Potentially* like the below:

```
(SELECT SUM(t2.TotDirectHrs) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.TicketDate) AS DaysDirectHrs FROM  AIM.dbo.AggTicket t2 WHERE t2.TicketDate = t.TicketDate) as DaysDirectHrs,
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#test') is not null
drop table #test

create table #test(id int identity(1,1), letter char(1))
insert into #test
values
('a'),
('b'),
('b'),
('c'),
('c'),
('c')
```

Given the data set above, suppose we wanted to get a count of all rows. That's simple right?

```
select 
    TheCount = count(*) 
from 
    #test

+----------+
| TheCount |
+----------+
|        6 |
+----------+
```

Here, no `GROUP BY` is needed because it's implied to group over all columns since no columns are specified in the `SELECT` list. Remember, `GROUP BY` *groups the SELECT statement results according to the values in a list of one or more column expressions. If aggregate functions are included in the SELECT list, GROUP BY calculates a summary value for each group. These are known as vector aggregates.[[MSDN]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql)*.

Now, suppose we wanted to count each letter in the table. We could do that at least two ways. Using `COUNT(*)` with the `letter` column in the select list--or using `COUNT(letter)` with the `letter` column in the select list. However, in order for us to attribute the count with the letter, we need to return the letter column. Thus, we must include `letter` in the `GROUP BY` to tell SQL Server what to apply the summary table to.

```
select 
    letter
    ,TheCount = count(*) 
from 
    #test
group by
    letter

+--------+----------+
| letter | TheCount |
+--------+----------+
| a      |        1 |
| b      |        2 |
| c      |        3 |
+--------+----------+
```

Now, what if we wanted to return this same count, but we wanted to return all rows as well? This is where **window functions** come in. The **window function** works similar to `GROUP BY` in this case by telling SQL Server the set of rows to apply the aggregate to. Then, it's value is returned for for every row in this window / partition. Thus, it returns a column which is applied to every row making it just like any column or calculated column which is returned form the select list.

```
select
    letter
    ,TheCountOfTheLetter = count(*) over (partition by letter)
from 
    #test

+--------+---------------------+
| letter | TheCountOfTheLetter |
+--------+---------------------+
| a      |                   1 |
| b      |                   2 |
| b      |                   2 |
| c      |                   3 |
| c      |                   3 |
| c      |                   3 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

Now we get to your case where you want to use an aggregate and an aggregate in a window function. Remember that the return of the window function is treated like any other column, thus must be applied in the `GROUP BY`. Pseudo would look something like this, but window functions aren't allowed in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select 
    letter
    ,TheCount = count(*) 
    ,TheCountOfTheLetter = count(*) over (partition by letter)
from 
    #test
group by
    letter
    ,count(*) over (partition by letter)

--returns an error
```

Thus, we must a correlated sub-query or a cte or some other method.

```
select 
    t.letter
    ,TheCount = count(*) 
    ,TheCountOfTheLetter = (select distinct count(*) over (partition by letter) from #test t2 where t2.letter = t.letter)
from 
    #test t
group by
    t.letter

+--------+----------+---------------------+
| letter | TheCount | TheCountOfTheLetter |
+--------+----------+---------------------+
| a      |        1 |                   1 |
| b      |        2 |                   2 |
| c      |        3 |                   3 |
+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: SELECT @@VERSION returned "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )", so kudos for that. I was able to get your answer to execute and return what I had asked for. Before I select this as the answer, though, could you please explain why that field needs to be in the GROUP BY clause when it isn't even related to how the data is being partitioned let alone grouped? The other Msg 8120 errors I found seemed fairly obvious in comparison..

Comment: When you have an aggregate in a select statement, all other columns which you want to return that aren’t part of an aggregate must be included in the group by clause. Otherwise, there is no physical way to display accurate results. Your case can be confusing because it uses and aggregate. However, it uses an over clause which tells sql server the partition and then applies it in the row level. Remember that you always need to think in sets when thinking about SQL server and most relational databases

Comment: But @scsimon that field you told me is already inside an aggregate function. I'm partitioning the sets of that field by a different value that I'm not displaying nor grouping by. Why, oh why, must I put that field in the GROUP BY clause as well? My apologies if you already feel like you explained this, but I'm just not seeing why it needs that field to be both in an aggregate and the GROUP BY clause for it to properly display the set of information I'm querying...

Comment: @Smizles i tried to explain this in my edit.  hope this helps

Comment: I really appreciate the example! I guess I'm just thick-skulled because I can't see a possible scenario where it wouldn't know how to group the results of an aggregate-window function combo. The only way that what you said makes sense to me is if because the aggregate function is working within the window function I have to tell it that I would also like it to group by each unique result contained within the window of aggregates. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, basically. I can understand the thought that group by should be implied, but remember there is group by rollup and group by cube, etc...

Comment: Thanks @scsimon. Now I need to look up group by rollup and group by cube lol

Comment: The maze keeps getting longer I can assure you @Smizles